# Issue with setting text to edittext inside Expandablelistview

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I am using edittext in every last child inside expandablelistview. Edittexts are visible only if its checkbox is selected. That is working fine but the problem is when I select a new lastchild, the previous edittext,s value gets copied to this. Also when I scroll, edittext values of each child gets interchanged giving me a lot of trouble. How to fix this? I tried many methods. Unfortunately none of them worked. I am posting the code of getchildView here. Also I dont have any problem when dealing with visibility of edittexts.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int groupPos=groupPosition;
    final int childPos=childPosition;
    final boolean islstchild=isLastChild;
    final Industries_Level_3 child = (Industries_Level_3) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multilevel_list_item_child, null);
    }

    final EditText edtOther=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editIndOther);



    final CheckBox chkSelect=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxInd);
    chkSelect.setText(child.getIndname());

    if(child.getSelected()!=null)
    {
    chkSelect.setChecked(child.getSelected());

    if (isLastChild) {
        if (child.getSelected()==true) {            
            edtOther.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            edtOther.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }else
    {
        edtOther.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    }

    /*Setting text to edittext*/
    if(child.getOtherText()!=null)
    {
        if(child.getOtherText().length()>0)
        {
            edtOther.setText(child.getOtherText().toString());
        }
    }
    chkSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(chkSelect.isChecked())
            {
                if(islstchild)
                {
                    edtOther.setText("");
                    edtOther.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    edtOther.requestFocus();

                }
                    grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().get(childPos).setSelected(true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                if(!islstchild)
                {
                    int count=0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group()
                        .size(); i++) {
                    if (grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().get(i).getSelected()==true) {

                        if(i!=grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().size()-1)
                        {
                        count = count + 1;
                        }

                        if (count == grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().size()-1) {
                            grouplist.get(groupPos).setSelected(true);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                }   
                }


            }else
            {
                if(!islstchild)
                {
                grouplist.get(groupPos).setSelected(false);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else
                {
                    edtOther.setText("");
                    child.setOtherText("");
                    edtOther.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().get(childPos).setSelected(false);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    });


    edtOther.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text= edtOther.getText().toString();
            child.setOtherText(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

**UPDATE: FULL CODE**

```
public class IndBussinessAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

LayoutInflater inflater;

/* list of group */
private List<IndustryGroup_Level_2> grouplist;

public IndBussinessAdapter(Context context,
        List<IndustryGroup_Level_2> bsgrouplist) {
    super();
    this.grouplist = bsgrouplist;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    List<Industries_Level_3> ch = grouplist.get(groupPosition)
            .getIndustry_Based_On_Group();
    return ch.size();
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final int groupPos=groupPosition;
    final int childPos=childPosition;
    final boolean islstchild=isLastChild;
    final Industries_Level_3 child = (Industries_Level_3) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multilevel_list_item_child, null);
    }

    final EditText edtOther=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editIndOther);

    /*Setting text to edittext*/
    if(child.getOtherText()!=null)
    {
        if(child.getOtherText().length()>0)
        {
            edtOther.setText(child.getOtherText().toString());
        }
    }

    final CheckBox chkSelect=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxInd);
    chkSelect.setText(child.getIndname());

    if(child.getSelected()!=null)
    {
    chkSelect.setChecked(child.getSelected());

    if (isLastChild) {
        if (child.getIndname().startsWith("Other") && child.getSelected()==true) {          
            edtOther.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            edtOther.requestFocus();

        } else {
            edtOther.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }else
    {
        edtOther.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    }

    chkSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(chkSelect.isChecked())
            {
                if(islstchild)
                {

                    edtOther.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    edtOther.requestFocus();

                }
                grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().get(childPos).setSelected(true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                if(!islstchild)
                {
                    int count=0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group()
                        .size(); i++) {
                    if (grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().get(i).getSelected()==true) {

                        if(i!=grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().size()-1)
                        {
                        count = count + 1;
                        }

                        if (count == grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().size()-1) {
                            grouplist.get(groupPos).setSelected(true);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                }   
                }


            }else
            {
                if(!islstchild)
                {
                grouplist.get(groupPos).setSelected(false);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else
                {
                    edtOther.setText("");
                    child.setOtherText("");
                    edtOther.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                grouplist.get(groupPos).getIndustry_Based_On_Group().get(childPos).setSelected(false);
                notifyDataSetChanged();





            }
        }
    });


    edtOther.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text= edtOther.getText().toString();
            child.setOtherText(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public IndustryGroup_Level_2 getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return grouplist.get(groupPosition);
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return grouplist.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int gpos=groupPosition;

    final IndustryGroup_Level_2 group = (IndustryGroup_Level_2) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        if (groupPosition==(grouplist.size())-1) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multilevel_list_item2,
                    null);
        } else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multilevel_list_item,
                    null);
        }
    }
    if (groupPosition==(grouplist.size())-1) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multilevel_list_item2,
                null);
    } else {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multilevel_list_item,
                null);
    }

    TextView groupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textListItem);
    groupName.setText(group.getIndgroupname());
    final CheckBox chkSelect=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxInd);
    final EditText edtOther=(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextOtherGroup);

    if (gpos==grouplist.size()-1) {

        if (group.getSelected()) {
            edtOther.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            edtOther.requestFocus();

        } else {
            edtOther.setText("");
            edtOther.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }else
    {
        edtOther.setText("");
        edtOther.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(group.getSelected()!=null)
    {
    chkSelect.setChecked(group.getSelected());
    }



    chkSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Arraylist size "+grouplist.size());
            System.out.println("Group position "+gpos);

            if(chkSelect.isChecked())
            {
                group.setSelected(true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();


                if(gpos!=grouplist.size()-1)
                {
                for(int i=0;i<group.getIndustry_Based_On_Group().size();i++)
                {
                    if(i!=group.getIndustry_Based_On_Group().size()-1)
                    {
                    group.getIndustry_Based_On_Group().get(i).setSelected(true);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                }
            }else
            {
                group.setSelected(false);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                if(gpos!=grouplist.size()-1)
                {
                for(int i=0;i<group.getIndustry_Based_On_Group().size();i++)
                {
                    if(i!=group.getIndustry_Based_On_Group().size()-1)
                    {
                    group.getIndustry_Based_On_Group().get(i).setSelected(false);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if(group.getOtherText()!=null)
    {
        edtOther.setText(group.getOtherText());
    }

    edtOther.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text=edtOther.getText().toString();
            group.setOtherText(text);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public Industries_Level_3 getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    List<Industries_Level_3> ch = grouplist.get(groupPosition)
            .getIndustry_Based_On_Group();
    return ch.get(childPosition);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are recycling `convertView` (good!), your `getView()` needs to reset any subviews in the recycled view to a pristine state.

In particular, you probably need to add something like

```
edtOther.setText(null);
```

right after the `findViewById()` where you init `edtOther`.

Comment: edtOther.setText(null); is not working.... When I use that it behaves like I havent written any code to save the typed text in edittext! :(

Comment: Reset to whatever default you need. If there's a value you need to set (and have stored somewhere else), set it.

Comment: I think I have already done it just above chkSelect.onclicklistener.  edtOther.setText(child.getOtherText().toString());

Comment: You're doing it conditionally in an if block. You need to reset the recycled view unconditionally.

Comment: As I am setting json parsed values by default, if do without if block it is giving nullpointerexception. coz not all have value in it.

Comment: The only problem is when typing in one edittext and then typing another . Setting default values to edittext is working fine.

Comment: I changed my method for doing this and now it is working fine. Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to inflate the `convertView` like this:

```
if (convertView == null) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.multilevel_list_item_child, parent, false);
}
```

**EDIT:**

You should have a private class on your adapter like this:

```
private static class GroupHolder {
    TextView groupName;
    CheckBox chkSelect;
    EditText edtOther;
}
```

And then, on your `getGroupView` you should have something like this:

```
GroupHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new GroupHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutGroup, parent, false);
        /* Initialize these three again like holder.groupName = convertView.findViewById...
        TextView groupName;
        CheckBox chkSelect;
        EditText edtOther;
        */
        convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
        holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

// and then set fields like this holder.groupName.setText(//TODO);
```

Comment: You should always use it like this anyways. Your problem can be a sum of many things.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this? :/

Comment: I changed my method for doing this and now it is working fine. Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't find a good solution for this problem. So I changed my approach. Instead of using Edittext I used Button and gave it an edittext like background. And in the onclick of the the button a Alertdialog comes and there the value is entered. And when selecting OK the typed text is set to the button. I think this is a way better option than using edittext in a list.

I used this code to give edittext background for button.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item>
          <shape >
          <solid android:color="#8C8F91" />
          </shape>
      </item>

  <!-- main color -->
  <item android:bottom="1dp"
      android:left="1dp"
      android:right="1dp">
      <shape >
          <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
      </shape>
  </item>

      <!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
      <item android:bottom="6dp">
          <shape >
              <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
          </shape>
          </item>
        </layer-list>
```

Code for showing alertdialog on buttonclick:

```
btnOther.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // get prompts.xml view
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
                if(child.getOtherText()!=null)
                {
                    userInput.setText(child.getOtherText().toString());
                }
            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                child.setOtherText(userInput.getText().toString());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    }
                  });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the `ExpandableListView` `layout_height` to "`match_parent`" and also make sure the `getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)` method is called always inside of `getChildView` to get a fresh copy of the data.